# How can I save a method chaining in a variable?

Tags: java

If I have this kind of method chaining:

```
private void returnThisResult(SomeResponse response, 
                              SomeRequest someRequest, 
                              SomeSession session) {

   session.setSomeResult(response.getSomeResult());
   session.setSomeID(response.getSomeID());

   if (config.getSomeResultFailed().equalsIgnoreCase(response.getSomeResult())) {
      logHelper.errorLog(trimThis(response
                                   .codeTriggered()
                                   .stream()
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(null)),
      response.getSomeResult(), 
      response.getSomeID(), 
      someLogRequest);
        
      throw new SomeException(SomeErrorCode).SOME_LIST);
}
```

How can I just save the **`logHelper`**  line in a variable or method so I can just use it to avoid repeating lengthy codes?

I tried the code below but the `()` at `withErrorLogging()` turns red without a hint:

```
void withErrorLogging() {
      logHelper.errorLog(trimThis(response
                                   .codeTriggered()
                                   .stream()
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(null)),
      response.getSomeResult(), 
      response.getSomeID(), 
      someLogRequest);
        
      throw new SomeException(SomeErrorCode).SOME_LIST);
}
```

Is there a way?

Comment: either you do it like this, or you create a reusable method for this call

Comment: *"How can I just save it in a [...] method"* by writing a method  that accepts whatever type `response` is, doesn't return anything (`void`) and simply runs that piece of code.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I tried the `void` approach [`void someLogging() { mentioned method chaining...`` }, yet I'm getting a red line at `()`. Why is that? Btw, I'm trying to create this method inside of another method, wherein the parameters of this method is being passed on the chained method I'm trying to shrink.

Answer (score 1):

Try with lambda, such as:

```java
Supplier<String> generator = () -> "Hello world";
callMethod(generator.get())

Consumer<Void> consumer = (Void) -> doSomething();
consumer.apply(null);
```

Wrap your message generator into Supplier or your method into Consumer.

Comment: instead of using Consumer with no/void input, use the Runnable interface.

Comment: @Pawan.Java Runnable is more appropriate

Comment: @shanfeng Hi, I updated the question. Would you mind taking a look? I tried the void approach yet the `()` got a red line. Also tried the with lambda, but the `<Void>` and `apply` gets red a line.

Comment: @Kyle Check syntax of the code. Seems `)` is redundant